# How to parse model attribute on rails before column type on database validates it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Well, I have a column on my postgres called `birthday` and I chose the column type [date](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html)

However, the input for it (in the application layer) can be  "10-10-10", for example.

So I created a callback on my model `before_validation :parse_birthday` to transform the string to a valid one.

```
def parse_birthday
   puts self.birthday
   self.birthday = Chronic::parse(self.birthday)
   ...
end
```

But inside the callback the birthday is `null`, because I guess the DB column type rejects dates with dashes and I can't do the parse before it.

So, how can I achieve that without changing the column type to a character varying?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model you can override the getter and setter methods for `birthday` something like this:

```
def birthday
  read_attribute(:birthday) || read_attribute_before_type_cast(:birthday)
end

def birthday=(_birthday)
  write_attribute(:birthday, (Chronic.parse(_birthday) || _birthday)) if _birthday
end
```

This means if the Chronic parse fails because the value of the date is nonsense, it will fail your normal presence validation because it becomes nil, but the value of the user entered will go back into the model for redisplay on the form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how can I make some validation with this value inside a callback if it retrieves nil? For example, if user is female, the birthday can be nil, otherwise must be not nill.

Comment: Just do your own validation as normal.  All this handles is parsing the value from the form, and putting back the value exactly as the user entered it.  So for your example you could just use a normal validator like `validates :birthday, presence: true, unless: :female?` along with a `female?` method that returns true/false according to your definition.  See the Rails guide on conditional validation for more on this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is overwrite the default setter, try something like this

```
  def birthday=(birthday_input)
    write_attribute(:birthday, Chronic::parse(birthday_input))
  end
```

This way, it will be written directly as you want it and your validations can run after the fact